# Why does fetching of compressed nfts by collection/owner not work?

Tags: metaplex, jsonrpc-api, nfts

Context: Ran the solana compressed nfts scripts successfully about 2 weeks ago from creating and minting to fetching by collection/owner using the `helius devnet rpc endpoint`.. This is the link to the compressed nft script:  https://github.com/solana-developers/compressed-nfts

Problem faced: However, when I ran it yesterday, minting and creating of nfts works but not fetching by collection/owner. Instead, it returns the following error : [image]

Past solutions: I have tried re-running the scripts in the same order as well as checked on the api end point spec from metaplex repo but didnt find any breaking changes..

Ask: Is there any way to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue were running into was actually a bug in both the script [repo you linked](https://github.com/solana-developers/compressed-nfts), as well as the RPC indexing code.

Specifically, with passing in a `page=0` value.

The correct value for the `page` parameter is `>0`. So when using the `getAssetsByGroup` and `getAssetsByOwner`, the first `page` will start with index of `1`.

I fixed the bug in the [compressed nft repo](https://github.com/solana-developers/compressed-nfts) you linked, and here is the [closed issue from that repo](https://github.com/solana-developers/compressed-nfts/issues/3) as well.